# Use a link as a form field without javascript

Tags: django, forms, form-submit

i'm almost done developing a search engine in django 1.3. I'm having some filters on the left side of my application.

What i want to do is display those filters as links (not as radiobuttons /selectbox /checkbox) and whenever a user clicks on one of those links, the form is resubmitted with that filter's value submitted (maybe grabbed by a TextInput widget)

Basically, something like the left side filtering in [this example from Google](http://www.google.it/search?hl=it&q=baloo&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=2389l2929l0l3097l5l3l0l0l0l0l90l200l3l3l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&biw=1280&bih=634&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi), but without javascript (so even a "non js user" can use my website)

Is it possible? How? Or am i bound to javascripts for this purpose?

Thanks all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply use GET query parameters?

Imagine the following:

- User searches for "bear", the URL becomes: /search/?q=bear
- The query parameters are handled by your view (collect all images corresponding to the query parameters)
- The query parameters are sent back to the template in a variable;
- Each filter link has the query parameters attached to it together with its own specific parameters, so that the filter link for e.g. medium-sized images becomes /search/?q=bear&size=medium;
- Upon clicking that filter link, your view will get a `q` and an `size` key in its request.GET dictionary;
- Repeat ad infinitum (e.g. /search/?q=bear&size=medium&expression=smiling&color=b-w&activity=dancing).

Comment: i'm still learning about url handling... can't i use GET and use urls formatted like /bear/medium/smiling/dancing/ ?

Comment: I suppose you could do that, but the main advantage of query parameters is that they are key-value pairs (e.g. size=medium), whereas in your URL formatting, you'd have to be very careful in retrieving the right values per filter option. What would you do for example with someone looking for a picture of any size of a smiling, dancing bear? `/bear/smiling/dancing`? How would you know "smiling" applies to the "expression" filter and not the "size" filter?

Comment: On the other hand, you could do something like: /bear/size/medium/expression/smiling/activity/dancing. In your URL conf, you'd have to write a regular expression that takes any amount of /parameter/value strings and turns them into key-value pairs. This does mean a lot of extra work and testing, and I'm not sure I see the added value in this.

Comment: within django you can config the url dispatcher to get the values from the urls based on their order and number. So, if i configure two urls /<who>/<size>/ and /<who>/<size>/<what>/ i can both use /bear/medium/ and /bear/medium/dance/ and know exactly where i am and what i'm getting

Comment: You can indeed, I'm just worried (maybe unnecessarily in your case) about the extensibility. As you derive the key name from the order (e.g. the first argument is the image size), what happens if you add filters, and if users don't filter on image size? How will you then know that the dance in /bear/dance does not relate to the image size? Honestly, key/value pairs are a more future-proof strategy (which is probably why the URL of the Google example you used is full of query parameters as well).

Comment: That's what i'm trying to figure out, i think this is done by named views, but i'm not sure about it, in my past django experiences i've been a mere python algorithm developer and didn't go too much in depth with the whole framework :(